# Spring MVC IllegalStateException Error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to create a simple test website using spring MVC and I cannot seem to get past the most simple case. I have a jsp website that is a "login" that has 2 inputs and a submit button, but it will not display anything except an error message. Using Spring 3.0.2 and Tomcat 6.0.29 Stand-alone.

IndexController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login.htm*")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginPage(Map model){
    UserAccess user = new UserAccess();
    model.put("user", user);    

    return "login";
}
```

login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form:form action="login.htm" commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Username:</td>
        <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Password:</td>
        <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My UserAccess class is nothing more then a username, password and a bunch of getter/setters, just like any bean should be. Enclosed it a picture of the error I get upon build, please let me know if you need any more information to help me. 
[image: Error Picture]

My servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

As well as my project's web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot believe I was so stupid. I figured out my own problem. This is why I hate Annotations... in my servlet.xml file, I had the component-scan scanning the wrong package, so none of my annotations were being picked up. Refactoring is a pain, eh?

TL;DR: Make sure you list the correct package in your servlet.xml under

Answer (score 1):

Your command name is not `user`, it's `userAccess`. The error is telling you it can't find a command name of user in your  tag.

Edit: Ok, consider splitting the model attribute out into it's own method using the [@ModelAttribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) annotation.

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
public UserAccess formBackingObject() {
    return new UserAccess();
}
```

Having said that what you've done should work. Alternatively try returning both the model and the view.

```
return new ModelAndView("login", model);
```

Perhaps its not picking up the model map in the signature... but I thought that would work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have double checked that, I've edited the post, I was trying everything to get it working and changed that, but even after changing it, it still doesn't work

Comment: I did the above and still get the same error. It's frustrating because I cannot find where the exact problem is. I've downloaded another example of this and matched it word for word and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Take the form stuff out of your login.jsp. Add some text or some other rubbish to the Model in the controller. On your login jsp, try and print out the Model attributes with <c:out/> - if you can't even see the text printed out, something's wrong in the controller. Consider swapping Map with Spring's ModelMap as a test in your controller method signature.

Comment: Sorry I had 2 separate suggestions in that comment. The first - leave the Map model parameter and add some more attributes to the map - e.g. try calling put("test", "sometext"), then on your login page try and print out the text - e.g. <c:out value="${test}"/>. If you can see the text on the screen "sometext" then you know the model stuff is working. If you can't, I'd try suggestion 2, which is changing Map to Spring's ModelMap in your controller.

Comment: Neither seem to work. If remove the form:form and just put in a c:out using with just Map or ModelMap nothing appears on screen.

Comment: While not getting the error, it's just giving me nothing, even the c:out isn't working.

Comment: I'm clutching at straws here, but you do have the C taglib imported correct? <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> Still... the fact that you can't even put simple text into the model and print it out on the screen is worrying - something is very stuffed that I can't see from here.

Comment: Yeah, I have it imported correctly. I know it's weird. Is there anything you can think of in the tomcat config or the web/servlet/context.xml files that might cause this?

Comment: Nope - never heard of those things impacting. The fact that your controller renders the view correctly means that everything should be set up, and the only problem is that the view can't find your model attributes. This issue is usually very simple to solve and I have no fricken clue what's wrong with yours.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Yeah, as I said, I tried with an example program and it worked, which frustrates me, but I can't really find an exact reason for it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you request directly for `login.jsp` instead of going through the Spring controller. That's why there's no user attached to your request by the time the JSP file is rendered, since the request has not involved the `DispatcherServlet` at all.

That is because your `welcome-file-list` points to `login.jsp` and I assume `login.jsp` is not located under `WEB-INF/{something}`, but it's in the root of the web application, therefore directly accessible.

To check if my assumption is right, try to request for: `http://localhost:8080/login.htm` instead of simply `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: I have it reuesting login.htm, but even if I directly request it myself, it still doesn't work